# Update Query based on condition

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements

I would like to do the following.
Update a field based on the value of another field like

```
update table set if(fielda=1){fieldb=2 fieldc=3}else{fieldd=2 fielde=3}
```

I know this is not valid mysql but its the best way for me to describe the problem.

Comment: The values of the fields is not important. if fielda=1 set datefielda=now() else datefieldb=now(). I hope this is more clear.

Comment: the "trick" we use is to assign values to all of those columns. In the case where we _don't_ want to change the value of a column, we simply assign it the current value. We use a conditional test (fielda=1) to decide whether we are assigning a new value, or whether we are keeping the value unchanged. That's the pattern we normally use to conditionally update a column based on some logical test that returns a boolean. See my answer. The answer from juergen d does the same thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
update table set
b = case when a = 1 then 2 else b end,
c = case when a = 1 then 3 else c end,
d = case when a = 1 then d else 2 end,
e = case when a = 1 then e else 3 end
```

### edit

according to your comment try this:

```
update table set
datefield_a = case when field_a = 1 then now() else datefield_a end,
datefield_b = case when field_a <> 1 then now() else datefield_b end
```

Comment: The values of the fields is not important. if fielda=1 set datefielda=now() else datefieldb=now(). I hope this is more clear.

Answer (score 2):

I think this syntax will achieve the result you attempted to specify.

```
UPDATE mytable
   SET fieldb = CASE WHEN fielda = 1 THEN 2 ELSE fieldb END
     , fieldc = CASE WHEN fielda = 1 THEN 3 ELSE fieldc END
     , fieldd = CASE WHEN fielda = 1 THEN fieldd ELSE 2 END
     , fielde = CASE WHEN fielda = 1 THEN fielde ELSE 3 END
```

The "trick" here is that we are updating all four columns, but in some "cases", we are assigning the current value of the column back to the column, resulting in no real change to the column value. (Once you get your mind bent around that idea, it's pretty easy.)

With MySQL, we do have a handy IF function (not available in most other RDBMS) that we can use to abbreviate that a bit, and achieve the same thing:

```
UPDATE mytable
   SET fieldb = IF(fielda = 1, 2, fieldb)
     , fieldc = IF(fielda = 1, 3, fieldc)
     , fieldd = IF(fielda = 1, fieldd, 2)
     , fielde = IF(fielda = 1, fielde, 3)
```

The pain is that you still have to repeat that same conditional test multiple times.

A single scan through the table (like these statements do), and getting all those assignments done in one fell swoop is going to be faster (and more efficient) than breaking this up and doing the assignments piecemeal using multiple statements.